# SQL command not properly ended - don't know why

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to work through this SQL query, and keep getting stuck with a

> SQL command not properly ended

statement.

The exact error is:

> ```
>  AND NOT PROJECT.dnum = EMPLOYEE.dno)) > 10
>                                      *
>  ERROR at line 4:
>  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> ```

Here is the schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
        fname VARCHAR(20), 
        minit CHAR(1), 
        lname VARCHAR(20), 
        ssn INT NOT NULL, 
        bdate VARCHAR(20), 
        address VARCHAR(40), 
        sex CHAR(1) check (sex IN ('M', 'F')), 
        salary INT CHECK (salary > 20000), 
        superssn INT,
        dno INT,
        PRIMARY KEY (ssn)
    );

    CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
        dname VARCHAR(20),
        dnumber INT NOT NULL,
        mgr_ssn INT,
        mgr_start_date VARCHAR(20),
        PRIMARY KEY (dnumber)
    );

    CREATE TABLE DEPTLOCATIONS (
        dnumber INT NOT NULL, 
        dlocation VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL check (dlocation IN ('BELLAIRE', 'SUGARLAND', 'HOUSTON', 'STAFFORD')),
        PRIMARY KEY (dnumber, dlocation)
    );

    CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
        pname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        pnumber INT NOT NULL,
        plocation VARCHAR(20) CHECK (plocation IN ('BELLAIRE', 'SUGARLAND', 'HOUSTON', 'STAFFORD')),
        dnum INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (pnumber)
    );

    CREATE TABLE WORKS_ON (
        essn INT NOT NULL,
        pno INT NOT NULL,
        hours FLOAT check (hours >= 5 AND hours <= 40),
        PRIMARY KEY (essn, pno)
    );

    CREATE TABLE DEPENDENT (
        essn INT NOT NULL,
        dependent_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        sex CHAR(1) check (sex IN ('M', 'F')),
        bdate VARCHAR(20),
        relationship VARCHAR(20) CHECK (relationship IN ('SPOUSE', 'SON', 'DAUGHTER')),
        PRIMARY KEY (essn, dependent_name)
    );
```

I'm attempting to  find employees whose salaries are
higher than the average salary of all the employees in the same department and who have two
or more dependents; then, for each found employee, I need to check if the employee works more than
a total of 10 hours a week on projects not controlled by their home department and
print the employee’s full name if so, along with salary, the number of dependents, the
total number of hours on projects controlled by the home department, and the total number of
hours on projects controlled by the other (i.e., non-home) departments

Here is my SQL query:

```
    SELECT concat(
    concat
    (EMPLOYEE.fname, ' '|| EMPLOYEE.minit), 
    ' '||EMPLOYEE.lname) as NAME, 
    EMPLOYEE.ssn,
    (select count(*) from dependent where Employee.ssn=dependent.essn) AS Num_Dependents, 

    (SELECT SUM(hours) FROM EMPLOYEE 
    JOIN WORKS_ON ON (EMPLOYEE.ssn = WORKS_ON.essn) 
    JOIN PROJECT ON (PROJECT.pnumber=WORKS_ON.pno) 
    WHERE PROJECT.dnum = EMPLOYEE.dno) 
    AS HOME_HOURS,

    (SELECT SUM(hours) FROM EMPLOYEE 
    JOIN WORKS_ON ON (EMPLOYEE.ssn = WORKS_ON.essn) 
    JOIN PROJECT ON (PROJECT.pnumber=WORKS_ON.pno) 
    WHERE NOT PROJECT.dnum = EMPLOYEE.dno) AS NOT_HOME_HOURS,

    (SELECT EMPLOYEE.salary FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE
    EMPLOYEE.salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE.dno = dno))

    AND 

    (SELECT SUM(hours) FROM EMPLOYEE 
    JOIN WORKS_ON ON (EMPLOYEE.ssn = WORKS_ON.essn) 
    JOIN PROJECT ON (PROJECT.pnumber=WORKS_ON.pno) 
    AND NOT PROJECT.dnum = EMPLOYEE.dno)) > 10  
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEPENDENT WHERE essn = ssn) >= 2;
```

I know it probably isn't formatted as nicely as it could be, but I've been at this for hours and nothing seems to get rid of that

> SQL command not properly ended

error which gets thrown when I run the query. Any help or tips would be much appreciate! Thanks all.

Comment: If you're using PL/SQL, doesn't that mean you're using Oracle, not MySQL?

Comment: The error message isn't the same as the code you posted. It shows two `))` after `EMPLOYEE.dno`, but your posted code only has `)`.

Comment: It also has `AND NOT`, but your code says `WHERE NOT`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for that, yup I have several different version in which I tweaked the query trying to get rid of that error; I made an edit and now the error reflects the query. I'll look into your second point, but I'm basically executing individual sql queries from the command line while ssh'd into a virtual Linux machine. I'll also check out that link you sent. Thanks for the help, but still stuck!

Comment: I just got the same thing from that link you posted, so one would correctly assume the execution should be flawless, however I still get that same error...

Comment: @Malky.Kid He's using Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar noted. Rescinding comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sql looks weird. Boiling it down to a simple representation, its structure appears to be something like (hopefully I understood the parentheses layout correctly) this:

```
SELECT
  (Query),
  (Query),
  (Query) AND (Query)
) dangling unrelated fragment
```

Oracle needs a FROM, and it can't cope with a select list that contains an AND like that..

> I know it probably isn't formatted as nicely as it could be

Absolutely 100% the problem.. By not laying out your SQL nicely you've become completely lost in the spaghetti, and you've ended up with an SQL that doesn't have a full set of matched brackets and is hence suffering from syntax errors

Here's what your sql looks like if I put it into a text editor and balance the parentheses up so each line that looks like `(query here) as alias,` occupies a single line:

[image]

You can see at the end an extra bracket creeps in and ends up wrecking things?

(Note for the "don't screenshot code" purists - did it deliberately to highlight the problem, as if it had been posted as text it would probably wrap and lose the impact)

Comment: If the main query doesn't need to select from a table, you can use `FROM DUAL` as a placeholder.

Comment: This is optional in MySQL, but other databases like Oracle require it.

Comment: This did it! At least partly, some other part I realized are incorrect are the order of the statements (just for clarity/sanity sake) as well as not aliasing properly. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In your code here:

**(** SELECT EMPLOYEE.salary FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE 
    EMPLOYEE.salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE.dno = dno) **)**

```
AND 

(SELECT SUM(hours) FROM EMPLOYEE 
JOIN WORKS_ON ON (EMPLOYEE.ssn = WORKS_ON.essn) 
JOIN PROJECT ON (PROJECT.pnumber=WORKS_ON.pno) 
AND NOT PROJECT.dnum = EMPLOYEE.dno)) > 10  
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEPENDENT WHERE essn = ssn) >= 2;
```

The opening and closing brackets (in bold) completes this Select statement without considering the select statement where you're summing up the hours. Hence, the overall structure while using a WHERE clause is affected.